# R: find all indeces of local minima below 0

Tags: r, if-statement, indexing

This is probably not very complicated, but I get confused by the if statements. I've got a large dataset and I'm looking for the indices of the mimima of pairs of two values below 0. Below is an example:

```
x <- c(-1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 1, 2, -1)
```

I am trying to find the indices of the values below 0 and in cases were two (or more) subsequent values are below 0, the index of the lowest value. So what I'd like to get is a vector like this

```
[1] 1 5 8
```

I've tried to solve this by looking at the derivative:

```
which(diff(sign(diff(test)))==2)+1
```

but that doesn't give me what I need, hence my failed attempt to try this with for loops and if statements

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with `tapply`:

```
idx <- which(x < 0)
unname(tapply(idx, c(0L, cumsum(diff(idx) > 1L)), function(i) i[which.min(x[i])]))
# 1 5 8
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c(-1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 1, 2, -1)
y = diff(x)
which((c(0,y)*c(-y,0)>=0) & ((c(0,y) + c(-y, 0))<0))

# [1] 1 5 8
```

To describe my answer:    `which((c(0,y)*c(-y,0)>=0))` is finding local min and max. then combine this with second term just choose local `min`.

If you are interested in values below zero you can add another conditions

```
which((c(0,y)*c(-y,0)>=0) & ((c(0,y) + c(-y, 0))<0) &(x<0))
```

If you want to select local `max`, you can change it to

```
which((c(0,y)*c(-y,0)>=0) & ((c(0,y) + c(-y, 0))>0))
# [1] 3 7
```

Answer (score 0):

an approach using `rle`

```
localmin <- function(x) {rlex <- rle(x<0)
                    rlex$values <- seq_along(rlex$values) *rlex$values
                    ix <- inverse.rle(rlex)
                    ixt <- tapply(seq_along(ix)[ix>0], ix[ix>0], function(i,xi) i[which.min(xi[i])],xi=x)
                    unname(ixt)
                    }


localmin(x)
# [1] 1 5 8
```